# EF Core deserialization of a database item into various types

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, json-deserialization

I have a range of entities which have a series of common properties being a `informationItem` and a series of specific entity properties which I intend to store as JSON property `Detail` in SQL Server; e.g.

```
    public class InformationItem
    {
        public Guid InformationItemId { get; set; }
        public InformationItemType Type { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }
    }
```

`InformationItemType` is from an enum with a collection of project elements such as Assumptions, benefits, constraints, tasks etc.. There are some 20 object types which specific specific `Detail` properties.

I don't want to have 20+ entity specific tables in the database but what I would like to do is 'inflate' them into their real concrete classes of Assumption, Benefit, Constraint, Task etc deserializing the JSON `Detail` into the specific properties of the type when entity framework does its 'magic'.

the main reason I am after this is that each entity will have lost of many to many relationships associated with them such as their relationship to a user etc and I don't wat the user to end up with multiple `virtual ICollection`s of the various types.

Is it possible to store `InformationItems` with a specific type identifier and Detail JSON information in the database and have EFCore return these as their concrete class types?